# Database tables generation using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to generate SQL tables using the sqlalchemy library.

I have two tables : **t_volume** and **t_volume_snapshot**

```
class Volume(...):
    """ Represent a volume element"""

    __tablename__ = "t_volume"

    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    volume_id = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    volume_name = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False)
    volume_type = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False)
    volume_disk_space = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class VolumeSnapshot(...):
    """ Represent a volume snapshot element"""

    __tablename__ = "t_volume_snapshot"

    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    volume_snapshot_id = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    volume_snapshot_name = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False)
    volume_id = Column(String(length=255), ForeignKey("t_volume.volume_id"))
```

I would like that a volume snapshot refers to a volume using the value *volume_id*. I tried to define the **t_volume_snapshot**.*volume_id* column as a ForeignKey pointing to **t_volume**.*volume_id* but all I get is

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1005, "Can't create table 'db.t_volume_snapshot' (errno: 150)")
```

I'm not used to sqlalchemy and SQL in general so I'm probably missing something...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like below

```
class Volume(...):
    """ Represent a volume element"""

    __tablename__ = "t_volume"

    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    volume_id = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    volume_name = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False)
    volume_type = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False)
    volume_disk_space = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    snapshots = relationship("VolumeSnapshot", back_populates="t_volume")

class VolumeSnapshot(...):
    """ Represent a volume snapshot element"""

    __tablename__ = "t_volume_snapshot"

    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    volume_snapshot_id = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    volume_snapshot_name = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False)
    snapshot_volume_id = Column(String(length=255), ForeignKey("volume_id"))
```

This should establish a bidirectional connection.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that ! (sorry, the "hello" at the begining didn't make it during the copy/paste and i couldn't edit my post ><)